# Install a shared printer on a workgroup computer as a local printer on a domain computer?

Tags: windows, printing, domain, workgroup

I'd like to install a local printer on a domain computer such that it's available for all users who subsequently login.  The printer itself is attached to a computer that isn't part of the domain but on the network and is shared as such.

I can already install it as a network printer as \workgroupcomp\printername but this only installs for one user.  I'd like it installed as a local printer such that it's available for all.

Any ideas?

Edit: Should have mentioned both computers are windows xp

Comment: I ended up kludging this with the following solution I found on another forum: you could create a simple batch file i.e printer.bat

the batch file would look like...

START \\SERVER1\PRINTER1
START \\SERVER1\PRINTER2

--------------------------------------------------

Then you could copy this batch file to the "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" folder and it will run everytime a user logs on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is in [KB307016](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307016).

Essentially what you do is to map lpt1 to the network printer and then use a registry hack to get it working on all the users.

Comment: That looks like it would work.  I'm going to give you the answer credit even though i actually already solved this with a slightly more kludgey solution.  I'll post my solution momentarily.